# how to retrieve the string of a QUrl with space in it?

Tags: qt, qurl

```
QUrl url("bword://blood transfusion");
QString res = url.toString();
```

Why I got the string "bword:" instead of "bword://blood transfusion"?

How can I get the string "bword://blood transfusion" form the QUrl?

Comment: check if url.isValid() is true or false. And try without the space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

URL syntax can be quite complex, see this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax). The problem is that your URL does not contain *authority* field, it only has *scheme* field "bword" and *path* "//blood transfusion". And according to the [RFC3986 - Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986.html):

> When authority is not present, the
>   path cannot begin with two slash
>   characters ("//").

So your URL is not valid (although `isValid()` returns true). Change your code to:

```
QUrl url("bword:/blood transfusion");
QString res = url.toString();
```

Comment: `bword:blood transfusion` would work too (assuming the system copes with URNs).

Comment: indeed, http:/foo bar works, so does http://foobar . The bug in QUrl seems to be that it partially parses urls - IMO it should just create an completely empty, invalid object (QUrl::isValid() == false) when parsing fails.

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  The url I got is from data file from stardict dictionary file. maybe I can only rebuild the dictionary to change the url.